Как побитово работают числа с фиксированной точностью в PostgreSQL?
Задача - представить полное побитовое представление числа с фиксированной точностью. Скажем, numeric(5,2).
С плавающей точкой имеет стандарт IEEE 754, поэтому легко понять, что 15.718 в real - это (-1)^S1.M10^(Ev), где S = 0, E = Ev + 127 = 130, M - дробная часть в 1.111..* 10^3, тогда SEM = 01000001011111011011111001110110 (с потерей точности).
Моя задача аналогично понять как представить число в numeric типе данных.

Нашел только объяснение на пальцах, дескать, с фиксированной точностью - это массив цифр + метаданные (типа количество цифр после запятой). Но побитово нигде нет, в том числе в доке постгреса.

Есть же исходники, если я всё правильно понимаю: https://doxygen.postgresql.org/pgtypes__numeric_8h_source.html Хотя тут только h файл, но структуру то видно.

@CrazyElf я не владею си, более того я впервые касаюсь постгреса после долгой работы с ораклом. Если вы можете считать структуру, то вероятно сможете ответить на мой вопрос?

Ну там нужно смотреть за что каждое конкретное поле отвечает. Там в каждом поле int, представить его в двоичном виде не проблема. Хотя странно, что на знак отведено тоже поле int, хотя там всего 3 значения возможны. Ну, в любом случае там просто подряд идут поля типа int, просто разбираетесь за что каждое поле отвечает и всё. Я только всё-равно не понял, зачем вам это всё изначально? Да, и в Оракле не похожая на эту структура? А то может там тоже самое почти, если вы там разобрались.

Читать вот тут: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_16_3/src/backend/utils/adt/numeric.c по коду можно начать с numeric_out (функция вывода в текстовое представление) и numeric_in (соответственно чтение из текстового ввода). Мне неинтересно расписывать огромную поэму несколько часов за полтора плюса репутации.

@CrazyElf вроде что-то считал. Интересно, что numeric и decimal в самоучителе представлены как примерно одно и тоже, хотя тут вроде как внутренняя структура отличается (подозреваю, что * означает указатель, но не факт). Насчет отдельного числа под знак - чат гпт тоже мне так сказала, я решил, что это очередная галлюцинация нейронки :)

@ВиталийЯндулов Это не примерно, это в точности одно и то же и вообще и в постгресе в частности. Просто в разных языках программирования это может называться или так или эдак, а может и одновременно и так и эдак как синонимы использоваться. Вот например https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730538/difference-between-decimal-and-numeric-datatype-in-psql

@CrazyElf, но ведь по вашей ссылке их объявление различается немного.

@ВиталийЯндулов Да, это интересно. Судя по этому файлу decimal - это numeric(30) или что-то типа того. Нужно дальше читать доки и т.д.
